# FS100 - MotoROS integration implications when MotoSight/Fit/COM are already setup

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, motoman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When using the controller FS100 what are the implications of integrating ROS with the other already purchased tools (MotoSight, MotoCOM and MotoFIT)

- Do they have to be uninstalled/dissabled temporarily or permanently?
- Could I switch from “ROS” operation to “Yaskawa” operation without any major changes, or what are the required changes?

I ask this because we have the intention of keeping projects just with Yaskawa software and initiate others in parallel with the ROS integration.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275452/fs100---motoros-integration-implications-when-motosight/fit/com-are-already-setup/) by [Danfoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32545/danfoa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2017-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To start, I'll say that you should not actively use those other applications concurrently with the MotoROS software.  It doesn't sound like that is your goal, but I want to provide that warning.  MotoROS is designed around the idea that the PC becomes the primary robot controller.  So you don't want any other applications trying to guide the FS100 controller while under ROS control.  Of course, there are safety mechanisms to prevent concurrent motion commands... but you don't want errors during operation.

Regarding whether you can leave the other applications on your controller:

- MotoCOM:  No problem.  The FS100 is just a server waiting for commands using a specific communication protocol.  This will always be available regardless of whether you are using ROS.  All of the application-logic is actually run on your Windows PC.  Just don't try to start another robot job from the PC while running your ROS application.
- MotoSight:  There are multiple editions of MotoSight, but I am assuming that you are using MotoSight2D Global Edition (most common).  This application does use some of the common resources that are shared by MotoROS.  But, I don't believe there are any conflicts to be concerned with.
- Having said that, please realize that the MotoSight2D communication driver will actively connect to your camera if it is on the network.  So, this could potentially interfere if you are also trying to also control the camera from the ROS PC.
- MotoFit: Unfortunately, I don't know the internal mechanisms of this application since it was developed by our Japan office.  So, I'm not 100% certain which API's it is accessing to perform it's function.  But I suspect that it may conflict with the motion API used by MotoROS.  Plus, it appears to use a lot of the common resources shared by MotoROS and MotoSight2D.  It would be best to remove this application from your controller.  Removing this application requires many changes to the FS100 internal parameters; so you should contact your local Yaskawa Motoman office for technical support. Be sure to ask them for help in making a "CMOS.BIN backup" first.  This is basically an image of your controller setup so that you can quickly/easily restore the controller to use MotoFit in the future.

---

Ted Miller - Yaskawa Motoman (US)

---

Originally posted by [millete](https://answers.ros.org/users/28748/millete/) with karma: 101 on 2017-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Danfoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32545/danfoa/) on 2017-11-09**:
Thank you very much Ted, I will contact the Japan Office to have a little bit more clearance over the MotoFit conflict and in case of new info I will posted here.